# How to load a video as a 4 dimensional tensor in tensorflow to train a 3D-CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I have a binary classification task at hand. I have created two folder of videos corresponding to the two classes. I have also created an annotation CSV which contains the path of the file and the class.

I am not able to find a way to create a generator which could load the MP4 video as a 4-D tensor using Tensorflow. I did it in PyTorch quite easily using torchvision.io.read_video function and extending the Dataset class. Is there any equivalent in Tensorflow?

I want to use it to train  video classifier 3D-CNN and want to feed it a 5D tensor of (batch_size, frames, height, width, channel)

PS: I don't want to save individual frames on disk.

Comment: I see you don't tag keras with tensorflow. Are you looking pure tf based operation?

Comment: I am much familiar with tf. If keras can do the job i  dont have  any problem.

Comment: I actually didn't mean their differentness. However, you can kick start with the `keras` code example [here](https://keras.io/examples/vision/), you can find 3D modeling, and video classification code examples. Also can follow [this](https://www.kaggle.com/ipythonx/tf-3d-2d-model-for-brain-tumor-classification/notebook) notebook, just for reference.  You can find some pre-trained 3D modeling information there.